# How to find the last 2 characters of Chinese names with command lines tools?

Tags: command-line, grep, sed, awk

I have a list of Chinese names, some of them have 2 characters, others may have more or less, like following:

[image]

I want to use some command lines tools, to find the last 2 characters of each. If doesn't 2 characters, ignore it.

The result will be:

[image]

How to do it with `grep`/`awk`/`sed`, or other tools?

---

Updated:

The characters are in gist now:

https://gist.github.com/freewind/6e67b76e8280ccea185c

Comment: @stackoverflow, can you stop thinking I'm spamming just because I've input some Chinese characters ?!

Comment: Can you paste the actual input? We can't test our solutions against images.

Answer (score 2):

Perl to the rescue:

```
perl -CSD -lne 'print $1 if /(..)$/' input-file
```

- `-CSD` turns UTF-8 on for input and output on STDIN, STDOUT and input and output streams.
- `-l` appends newline to `print`
- `-n` reads the input line by line

Comment: `-CIO` turns utf8 on for stdin and stdout. `-Cio` turns `:utf8` on for PerlIO's file input and output.  You probably want `-CIOio`